# Hover Multiple Elements

Tags: css

i want to ask you that is it possible to hover element when i hover "after" at the same time? without aiming on the element? i want to set an opacity to p element when i hover the afrer.I'm new in coding so i'll be happy if u can help me to solve this,Thanks in advance!

```css
*{

    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.container{
    position:relative;

}
.box{
    margin: 50px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-radius:20px;
}
.box::after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:30.5%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-top-left-radius:100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    background-color:#73688e;
    transition: 1s;
}
.box:hover:after{
    opacity:1;
    border-radius:20px;
    width:39%;
    height:100%;
}
.text{
    opacity:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, corrupti architecto voluptatum tempora magni non sapiente ab voluptates, quos obcaecati impedit, eos illo quia eveniet vel quibusdam perferendis incidunt minus.</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pointer-events` you can do this.

```css
.container{
    position:relative;
}
.box{
    margin: 50px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-radius:20px;
    pointer-events:none; /* added */
}
.box::after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:30.5%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-top-left-radius:100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
    background-color:#73688e;
    transition: 1s;
    pointer-events:initial; /* added */
}
.box:hover:after{
    opacity:1;
    border-radius:20px;
    width:39%;
    height:100%;
}
.text{
    opacity:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    transition: 1s;
}
/* added */
.box:hover .text {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events:initial; 
}
/**/
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, corrupti architecto voluptatum tempora magni non sapiente ab voluptates, quos obcaecati impedit, eos illo quia eveniet vel quibusdam perferendis incidunt minus.</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```